# Center of mass of vertices without enumeration?

Tags: convex-optimization, polyhedra, combinatorial-geometry

Given a $n$-dimensional convex polytope defined by $A x\leq b$ and $A_{eq} x = b_{eq}$, is there an efficient way to determine the average coordinates of all vertices without enumerating them? (As if each vertex was a point particle)

I am currently using a vertex enumeration program and then just averaging the results, but that seems a waste of memory - as I only want the average of the points and not the full enumeration as I can have relatively large $n$ and lots of constraints.

Comment: May I ask what you  need this particular center for? Other methods for computing the center may be more efficient; e.g., the analytic center, or the Chebyshev center.

Comment: We needed some central value, of which we thought the vertex average would be the easiest; but if other centers are easier to compute given the inequalities that can also work. Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest either the analytic center or the Chebyshev center, then.